React Native GooglePlacesAutocomplete Causes White Screen on Expo App
I'm using react-native-google-places-autocomplete in my Expo app to allow users to search for places. However, when I integrate the GooglePlacesAutocomplete component, the app shows only a white screen. I suspect it might be due to how I'm implementing it or possibly an issue with the API key or configuration. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Linking,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function NearbyPlacesScreen() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    latitude: 41.0082,
    longitude: 28.9784,
  });
  const [placeName, setPlaceName] = useState('');
  const [details, setDetails] = useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder="Where to?"
        onPress={(data, placeDetails = null) => {
          if (placeDetails) {
            setPlaceName(placeDetails.name);
            const { lat, lng } = placeDetails.geometry.location;
            setDetails(placeDetails);
            setLocation({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
          }
        }}
        query={{
          key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
          language: 'en',
          type: 'establishment',
          types: 'restaurant|cafe|food',
        }}
        fetchDetails={true}
        styles={{
          container: {
            width: '100%',
            paddingTop: 48,
          },
          textInput: {
            height: 44,
            fontSize: 16,
            borderRadius: 8,
          },
          listView: {
            overflow: 'hidden',
            borderRadius: 8,
          },
        }}
      />
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: location.latitude,
          longitude: location.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.1,
          longitudeDelta: 0.1,
        }}
      >
        {location && placeName && (
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
            }}
            title={placeName}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

Issue: The app displays a white screen whenever I include the GooglePlacesAutocomplete component. I have checked that my API key is enabled for the Places API and Maps JavaScript API on the Google Cloud Console, and I confirmed that other components render correctly if I remove this autocomplete component.
Additional Info:
I'm using Expo and running the app on a physical iOS device.
The API key has billing enabled, and I've tried both restricting it and leaving it unrestricted for testing.
There are no errors logged to the console.
Questions:
Is there anything specific to GooglePlacesAutocomplete on Expo that could cause this issue?
Are there known compatibility issues with Expo or iOS devices?
How can I debug this to find out where the issue might be originating?

import 'react-native-get-random-values';
solved my issue.
